# Stability of equilibrium points

Tags: recurrence-relations

Given the difference equation and the continuously differentiable function $g$:
$$x(n+1)=x(n)+h\times g(x(n))$$
Determine conditions on $h$ for which an equilibrium point is asymptotically stable, respectively unstable.

Comment: I just don't get how can you determine h without knowing g?

Comment: Presumably, the conditions on $h$ will involve $g$ in some way. Most likely the derivative of $g$ at the equilibrium point (which will be a zero of $g$).

Comment: I have gotten to this point by myself but I just don't see any relation between g(x)=0 and g'(x)<0

Comment: What makes you think you need such a relation?

Comment: sorry f'(x)<1 where x is the equilibrium point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** From the comments, I infer that you are familiar with the requirements for stability of fixed points for the difference equation $x(n+1)=f(x(n))$. In the case you are asking about, you have
$$ f(x)=x+hg(x) $$
for some function $g$ and a constant $h$.
So you just need to insert this function $f$ into the criteria you already know, maybe pretty up the result a little, and you're done!

Comment: can you be more clear please?

Comment: What relevant stability criteria *do* you know for the case $x(n+1)=f(x(n))$? Oh never mind, you have stability for $|f'(x_0)|<1$ and instability for $|f'(x_0)|>1$, where $x_0$ is the equilibrium point, right? Now insert $f'(x_0)=1+hg'(x_0)$.

Comment: With absolute values, yes. See my previous comment, which I amended as you were writing yours.

Comment: I know this but do I just leave g'(x0) as it is?

Comment: Sure, what else can you do? You don't know anything more about $g$, remember. Your problem seems to be that you think the question is asking more than is reasonable.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I had done the above reasoning myself but I thought that I had to take care of g as well. Anyway thanks for the help.